# How to count unique values a column in R

Tags: r, database, count

I have a database and would like to know how many people (identified by ID) match a characteristic. The list is like this:

```
111   A
109   A
112   A
111   A
108   A
```

I only need to count how many 'ID's have that feature, the problem is there duplicated ID's. I've tried with

`count(df, vars = ID)`

> but it does not show the total number of ID's, just how many times they are repeated. Same with

`count(df, c('ID')`

as it shows the total number of ID's and many of them are duplicated, I need to count them one single time.

> Do you have any suggestions? Using table function is not an option because of the size of this database.

Comment: How is question different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62500617/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-all-unique-values-in-a-column-in-r-language)? If you find it different from the duplicate therein, say so *there*. Edit the question making the difference clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `n_distinct()` from `dplyr` to count the number of unique values for a column in a data frame.

```
textFile <- "id var1
111   A
109   A
112   A
111   A
108   A"

df <- read.table(text = textFile,header = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
df %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(id))
```

...and the output:

```
> df %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(id))
  count
1     4
```

We can also summarise the counts within one or more `by_group()` columns.

```
textFile <- "id var1
111   A
109   A
112   A
111   A
108   A
201   B
202   B
202   B
111   B
112   B
109   B"

df <- read.table(text = textFile,header = TRUE)
df %>%  group_by(var1) %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(id))
```

...and the output:

```
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  var1  count
  <chr> <int>
1 A         4
2 B         5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first remove duplicates using `unique` and then `count`the remaining rows :

```
d <- tribble(
~ID,~feature,  
111,   "A",
109,   "A",
112,   "A",
111,   "A",
108,   "A")

count(unique(d,vars = c(ID, feature)),vars=ID)

   vars     n
  <dbl> <int>
1   108     1
2   109     1
3   111     1
4   112     1
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment : still new to SO, updated my answer.